# How to perform DialogInput operation within Button

Tags: dialog-window, button

Can someone clarify how to perform a `DialogInput` operation within a `Button`?
I wrote some code for that but it's not working.

```
Button["Enter value", 
 DialogInput[{name = ""}, 
  Column[{InputField[Dynamic[name], String], 
    Button["Hi", Dynamic[name]]}]]]
```

My problem is this — when I  run the above code, the given text is displayed but when I click on the button, the actual operation is not being carried out.

Comment: Please make a better effort to use proper capitalization and fewer ellipsis........

Comment: But, the above `DialogInput` works as you expect and want when run in the notebook and not from a button?

Comment: I mean, the button issue is probably fixed by adding `Method->"Queued"` to the button, but even so, is that your only problem?

Comment: What is the "Hi" button supposed to do?

Comment: What is the meaning of `Method-> "Queued"` ??

Answer (score 4):

As Rojo has pointed out, `Method -> "Queued"` can be used for the `Button` to wait for the dialog to appear, be evaluated, and return. I assume you want to use the value of `name` in some outer computation, so I forwarded it via a `DialogReturn` and therefore it is made global (while `name` inside `DialogInput` is local). Note that `DialogReturn` is the standard way to return values from a dialog.

```
Dynamic@output

Button["Enter value", 
 output = DialogInput[{name = ""}, 
   Column[{InputField[Dynamic[name], String], 
     Button["Accept", DialogReturn[name]], 
     Button["Reject", DialogReturn[]]}]], Method -> "Queued"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Accepting the input text updates the value of `output` in the first line (`Out[1]`).